# Find oracle records from the past 12 hours

Tags: sql, oracle

I am really having trouble trying to figure out how to find certain records from the past 12 hours using ORACLE.  I want to add the time check at the end of the following statements:

```
SELECT ND_TICKET.TICKET_ID, ND_TICKET.PRIORITY, ND_TICKET.PROBLEM_SUMMARY 
  FROM ARADMIN.ND_TICKET 
       INNER JOIN SUPPORT_AREA 
               ON (ND_TICKET.SUPPORT_AREA_ID = SUPPORT_AREA.SUPPORT_AREA_ID) 
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(SUPPORT_AREA.SUPPORT_AREA_NAME,'National\s+Technical') 
   AND ND_TICKET.PRIORITY IN( 0, 1 )
```

I have looked quite a few places but none of it really makes any sense to me.

I have a column named `TTR_START` that stores the number of second since January 1, 1970 (i.e. Unix time) that I want to use to make this date comparison.

Comment: is there any column where you store the insertion date?

Comment: @Sebas - The date is stored in TTR_START which is in epoch time.

Comment: There is no data type "epoch time" in Oracle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ttr_start` is a number that is the Unix time (seconds since Jan 1, 1970),

```
AND date '1970-01-01' + nutodsinterval( ttr_start, 'SECOND' ) >= 
       sysdate - interval '12' hour
```

should work.

If there is an index on `ttr_date` it would probably be more efficient to go the other way and convert the date of 12 hours ago to a number

```
AND ttr_start >= ((sysdate - interval '12' hour) - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60
```

Rather than embedding these calculations in every SQL statement, I would assume that you would want to define some utility functions to convert between actual dates and your numeric data.  Something like

```
CREATE FUNCTION epoch_to_date( p_epoch_num IN NUMBER )
  RETURN DATE
IS
  l_dt DATE;
BEGIN
  l_dt := date '1970-01-01' + numtodsinterval( p_epoch_num, 'SECOND' );
  RETURN l_dt;
END;

CREATE FUNCTION date_to_epoch( p_dt IN DATE )
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  l_epoch_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
  l_epoch_num := (p_dt - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60;
  RETURN l_epoch_num;
END;
```

Then, your queries could be

```
AND epoch_to_date( ttr_start ) >= sysdate - interval '12' hour
```

or

```
AND ttr_start >= date_to_epoch( sysdate - interval '12' hour )
```

Comment: Tried it and got the following error.
`17:54:13  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 932, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE`  Is this because of the epoch time and real time in SYSDATE?

Comment: @jmg0880 - Missed the fact in your comments that you're storing the date in a `NUMBER` data type.  You don't specify what epoch you're using so I've guessed that you mean that you're using the Unix epoch and you're storing the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970.